# Does a Cable Modem work like a DSL Modem when it comes to use a Router?

Tags: router, cable-modem

Long title, short question :) I moved over from Europe to the USA. In Europe, I am used to DSL (over the phone line), but here in California, Internet over the TV Cable seems to be most common, with Cox being the provider that seems to have a monopoly in my area.

But anyway, I would get a Cable modem from them, which has a normal LAN Port. Do I need any special router, or can I just grab any router from the store (e.g., the [Netgear WNR2000](http://netgear.com/Products/RoutersandGateways/WirelessNRoutersandGateways/WNR2000.aspx))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a special router; the one you listed should work fine.